# The shortest way to count vowels in C#

Tags: c#, regex

There were similar questions here, but my question is a bit different.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your word");
string fWord = Console.ReadLine();
string nWord = Regex.Replace(fWord, "[euioa]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);               
int number = fWord.Length - nWord.Length;
Console.WriteLine("Number of vowels equals " + number);
```

This program counts the number of vowels but is it possible to make it even shorter? Can I squeeze int number inside the WriteLine command somehow, avoiding this separate line of code?

Will it be shorter without subtracting operation?

Comment: You can put everything in one line, but that would not make it very readable.

Comment: use the pattern `[^aeiou]+` to remove all that is not a vowel.

Comment: Extract the code into its own method, then you can call it on the same line as the WriteLine call.

Comment: or search the vowel one by one instead of replacing them and count the number of results.

Answer (score 4):

A regex? Wow. Yes, it can be a lot shorter:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your word");
var word = Console.ReadLine();

var vowelCount = word.Count("aeiouAEIOU".Contains);

Console.WriteLine("Number of vowels equals " + vowelCount);
```

Comment: Good call @LucasTrzesniewski

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn;t know how to count directly so decided to subtract strings in the initial example.

Answer (score 0):

Another shorter version using regular expression matches function & count property is below:

> working code snippet:

```
      Console.WriteLine("Enter your word");
      var word = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Your total number of vowels is: {0}", new Regex(@"[aeiouAEIOU]+").Matches(word).Count);
```